# I need to apply two formulas in one cell (one formula is logic one)

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

[image: Sample table]

I’m currently working on a Risk Register document in Excel and have populated 2 separate columns: 1) Risk Impact and 2) Risk Probability

Both of those fields can have values from 1 to 5. It depends how Impact and Probability will of risks will be assessed.

I have a 3rd column called “Risk Severity” where I want to be able to show the result of multiplications of columns “Risk Impact” and “Risk Probability” and also apply a logic formula on top of that result(number). For example, if number is within 21-25 then I want to show a word “Critical”. If a number is within 15-21 range then it should show a word “high” etc.

I have used this type of formula: `=IF(Q6*R6=S6>=21,S6<=25,”Critical”,”Fail”)` but it doesn’t even work...

I’m attaching a screenshot here and I would really appreciate any type of assistance here.

Comment: Your `IF` statement is not structured correctly.  It should be `(logical_test, value_if_true, value_if_false)`.  You have 4 sections, when you can only have 3.  And your `logical_test` needs to have only one comparison, i.e. `=` or `>=` but not both.

Answer (score 0):

> For example, if number is within 21-25 then I want to show a word “Critical”. If a number is within 15-21 range then it should show a word “high” etc.

and use the 26 in this statement :

> =IF(Q6*R6=S6>=21,S6<=25,”Critical”,”Fail”)

```
=IF(AND((Q6*R6)>=15,(Q6*R6)<21),"High",IF(AND((Q6*R6)>=21,(Q6*R6)<25),"Critical",IF((Q6*R6)<15,"Out of Range","")))
```

to break it down.. saperate the IF() and their AND() conditions.. since you didn't define what will exactly will 21 refers to, so I'd assume one. (According to your statement 21 can either be "Critical" of "High").

Please try to gasp the `if (condition1_happen , do_this1, else if (condition2_happen , do_this2, else if (condition3_happen , do_this3, else "ShowError" ) ) )`  concept in the formula. Please share if you are stuck.

Hope it helps. ( :